# Converting a Protocol Buffer to a POJO

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is there a tool or library that can map a Protobuff object to a POJO. I would like to have the pojo implement other interfaces that I can not with the ProtoBuff object. Or would I have to manually do this conversion?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe too late, but you can try [protobuf-converter](https://github.com/BAData/protobuf-converter) library. It is easy to use.

Convert POJO object to related protobuf message:

```
POJOClass pojoInstance = new POJOClass();
...
ProtobufClass protoInstance = Converter.create().toProtobuf(ProtobufClass.class, pojoInstance );
```

Code for backward conversion:

```
POJOClass pojoInstance = Converter.create().toDomain(POJOClass.class, protoInstance);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ProtoStuff](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff).
I think it will do what you want.

I believe that you will want to use the "java-bean" compiler.

**Edit:** Changed the link.

Comment: For any other visitor like me: The link is not valid any more, so take a look here: http://www.protostuff.io/ or at github: https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff

Comment: Would love if there were an example of how to do this -- not clear from looking at the ProtoStuff API or documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is too late, but it might help others.

You may use https://gitlab.com/protobuf-tools/proto_domain_converter

It is very similar to protobuf-converter  but I'm actively maintaining it, it has better performance, supports map type and polymorphism (oneof).

Comment: Does `proto_domain_converter` convert nested classes? I found that protobuf-converter doesn't, and you have to convert the inner classes manually

Comment: @LewisMunene I am not sure I understand what you need but I try my best to answer.
Nested protobuf messages are supported. Static inner classes classes are supported as well. Non static inner classes are not supported out of the box since they need a wrapper class context in order to be created. However, you can use a custom mapper in order to convert a specific such class

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I wanted to convert a protobuf message that has a repeated field such as follows:
`message A {}`
`message B {
 repeated A a  = 1;
}`

I'll try it out. Thanks again