# Converting POJO to protocol buffer request message

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, retrofit

Instead of using a Relationship.RelationshipGetRequest as a request and response.  Is there any way to convert the request/response to a POJO?

I've seen this solution but its a bit more complicated than what I'm looking for:
[Converting a Protocol Buffer to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261372/converting-a-protocol-buffer-to-a-pojo?rq=1)

I'm using Retrofit and Google Protocol Buffers.

What I have:

```
public interface RelationshipService {

    @POST("/relation/get")
    Observable<Relationships.RelationshipGetResponse> getRelationship(
            @Body() Relationship.RelationshipGetRequest request
    );
}
```

What I want to use:

```
public interface RelationshipService {

    @POST("/relation/get")
    Observable<Relationship> getRelationship(
            @Body() Relationship request
    );
}
```

Relationship:

```
public class Relationship {
    private long mRelationshipId;
    private String mName;
    // etc. about 10 other properties..
}
```

My Request ends up being like this where the request has to be built here..

```
mClient.createService(RelationshipService.class).getRelationship(Relationships.RelationshipGetRequest.newBuilder().setRelationshipId(-1).build()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Relationships.RelationshipGetResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Error! " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Relationships.RelationshipGetResponse relationship) {

                String output = relationsip.getRelationship().getName();
                Timber.i(output);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own adapters to convert protobuff messages to your POJO instances. Otherwise you can try protostuff where you can use your existing POJOs as schema.
Check this:
https://github.com/anirbanroy88/services/tree/master/protostuff