# How to convert protobuf to POJO/JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, protocol-buffers, pojo

I am using "protobuf" format in place of JSON (as "protobuf" is optimized in comparison to JSON ) for fetching data from server.But my requirement is to convert protobuf to already existed POJO class(Mapped with realm entity).

I am using Protobuf-lite. There is any way to convert it in POJO/JSON in Android.

In android generated class is:

```
    public  static final class Person extends
                     com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite<
                          Person, Person.Builder> implements
                            PersonOrBuilder {
    }
```

And [Protobuf-Converter](https://github.com/BAData/protobuf-converter) does not support this type generated class.

So this converter is not helpful for me in android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Protocol Buffer to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261372/converting-a-protocol-buffer-to-a-pojo)

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is not duplicate. Actually in android we use Protobuf-lite that doesn't contain  "Converter" class. So i am not able to use the above(Converting a Protocol Buffer to a POJO ) approach.

Comment: what you mean by "we"? simply add the converter instead of writing a new one.