# Converting probuf to POJO

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I try to convert POJO to protobuf. This is very same that I want to do.(https://github.com/BAData/protobuf-converter, [Converting a Protocol Buffer to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261372/converting-a-protocol-buffer-to-a-pojo/37156910#37156910))

But, It doest not support Map type in protobuf. So, When I try to convert protobuf's map<string, string> to Java's Map<String, String> error occur.

Is there any easy way to do this job?

Comment: Would be easy to help you if you post some code and the error logs.

Comment: The protobuf built-in API already gives you a `map<string, string>` as a `Map<String, String>` without any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late.

Try https://gitlab.com/protobuf-tools/proto_domain_converter.
I wrote it after encountering some limitations in https://github.com/BAData/protobuf-converter.

It looks much like protobuf-converter but:

- It supports map type
- It supports polymorphism (oneof)
- It has
  better performance since it processes the annotations on compile time rather than runtime.